# IDO program for saling token using Anchor

Tags: spl-token, token-sale-program

I'm looking for the code example of the IDO program using off-chain signature or Merkle tree. Does anyone know where I can find it?

The idea is to use the off-chain signature or Merkle tree to conduct a whitelist for participants of the IDO, for example, account A only can buy a maximum of N tokens.

Comment: Needs more details / clarity. Hard to understand what you mean. There is an IDO pool program in anchor test directory but nothing about a merkle tree or off chain signer. The only merkle tree code I know about is an airdrop mechanism

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What I mean is using off-chain signature or Merkle tree to conduct a whitelist for participants of the IDO, for example, account A only can buy a maximum of N tokens.